# Docker with yarn

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yarnpkg

First time trying to get yarn and docker working together.
How can I stop yarn from installing the packages every single time I run `docker build` command?

I've found some solutions like storing `node_modules` in a temporary directory and then linking it, but with various packages installed I get too many errors to handle. Is there maybe a way to compare my `yarn.lock` with the one existing inside Docker or any other solutions?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.1-alpine

COPY package.json yarn.lock /usr/src/
RUN cd /usr/src \
    && yarn install --pure-lockfile

COPY . /usr/src
EXPOSE 3005
```

With this setup I get a message saying `Sending build context to Docker daemon  375.2MB`, then the `yarn install` is run as usual, fetching the packages every single time.

Comment: Have you looked into using a `.dockerignore` file to your setup?

Comment: @DanielD Any more details on the approach?

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file. This might be able to help you out. It's similar to using a `.gitignore` file. If looks helpful I'll write up a quick answer for future use.

Comment: What it does is excludes the files when adding them. I'm not adding `node_modules` into docker, they are generated by `yarn install`.

Comment: What do you have in your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @kichik Currently some crappy code as this is work in progress. The last time I tried I had a code that looked pretty much the same (with a running CMD) as Stefano answer

Comment: Docker caching is very fragile. "Pretty much the same" can be a huge difference. Please include the actual `Dockerfile` you tried and caused this issue. Otherwise it's impossible to reproduce the issue and help you without guessing.

Comment: @kichik Added the edit!

Comment: So that last part you added about 375MB definitely means you need to add `.dockerignore`. It will speed things up a lot if you ignore `node_modules` and let Docker cache it in the build. But on to the build, are you saying it reinstalls packages even when you run `docker build` two times in a row without changing anything? That's [not what's supposed to happen](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache). If that's the case, you should add even more details with a complete minimally reproducible example (files, commands, the works).

Answer (score 15):

Definitely pay attention to docker caching. Basically you want to run the most stable instructions earlier than less stable ones. Instructions which would result in the same image changes as an earlier run should not be rerun (exluding issues with ENV/ARG instructions). But once an instruction does need to be run, all instructions following will be run regardless of what's in the cache.

.dockerignore will also help, but it can be easy for things to slip in. I've adopted the practice of inverting the file by ignoring everything and then specifying exactly what should be copied.

To minimise fetching from the web, I like using the yarn offline cache. This stores the tarballs of installed dependencies and reuses them for future installs. You get the benefit over `npm rebuild` of fresh installs every time (if the cache has been invalidated). You configure the offline cache with a .yarnrc file which could be in your home directory but for this purpose you keep one in your repo along with a directory to store the tarballs.

You have the option of checking-in the mirror directory to your repo. A typically large npm module install will still only be in the region of 20 megs.

If you use the files below, customised for your needs, and run `yarn` locally, the yarn-offline-mirror will contain the tarballs needed to install the app.

.dockerignore

```
*

!yarn-offline-mirror/
!src/
!package.json
!yarn.lock
!.yarnrc
```

.yarnrc

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1

yarn-offline-mirror "./yarn-offline-mirror"
```

Dockerfile

```
ENV HOME /usr/src/
WORKDIR $HOME

# copy the tarballs
COPY ["yarn-offline-mirror", "$HOME/yarn-offline-mirror/"]

# copy files needed for the install
COPY ["package.json", "yarn.lock", ".yarnrc", "$HOME/"]

# the offline flag will mean that an error is raised if any
# module needs to be fetched remotely. It can be removed to allow
# yarn to fetch any missing modules if that was to happen.
RUN yarn --offline --frozen-lockfile --link-duplicates

# copy the rest.. could be further broken up into multiple instructions
# for cache optimisation
COPY . $HOME

CMD npm start
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use the docker cache better.

If you have your Dockerfile prepared as follows:

```
FROM node:carbon

COPY package.json yarn.lock /app
RUN cd /app \
    && yarn install --pure-lockfile

COPY . /app
CMD doStuff
```

The `docker build` won't touch the `package.json` unless it has changed. The next RUN command won't execute unless the cache has been invalidated in the earlier step.

NOTE: keep the `node_modules` inside your `.dockerignore` file